# Criar um botão para sair da app

Tags: android, app, button

Criei este código para fechar app para ela em vez de fechar a reinicia.
tenho das Mainactivity sendo que a primeira tem uma splash screen. O que tenho que mudar .

public void existeapp (View View ){
        existeapp();
    }

```
private void existeapp() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar `this.finishAffinity()`, mas acredito que só funcionaria na activity launcher. [De acordo com a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()), esse método fecha a activity atual e todas que estiverem abaixo na pilha.

Comment: muito obrigado xD

Answer (score 0):

No Android não tem maneira de "fechar" efetivamente uma aplicação, só quem faz isso é o sistema operacional.

O que você pode fazer é informar ao sistema que deseja finalizar todas as Activitys do seu aplicativo, ele continuará sendo mostrado na lista de apps recentes, porém, ao abrir começará da Activity Launcher.

**Em API's 16+**

Para isso retire o   `System.exit(0);` e substitua o `finish()` por `finishAffinity()`

**Em Api's 11+**

Substitua tudo pelo código de criação de um Intent com as Flags NEW_TASK e CLEAR_TASK.

Seu método ficará então :

**16+**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finishAffinity();

        }
```

**11+**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClasseInicial.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ja me ajudou e muito :)